# BrowserComponent not working in iOS but worked in android

Tags: codenameone

I wanted to use BrowserComponent to build an app for website. It worked as expected in android but did not work in iOS. It will just show the back, next and home button in the south of main form. See the code below

```
Form hi = new Form(new BorderLayout());
    hi.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    hi.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    hi.getTitleStyle().setAlignment(2);
    BrowserComponent don = new BrowserComponent();
    don.setURL("http://www.mywebsite.org");
    don.setPinchToZoomEnabled(true);
    don.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    don.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    don.setSmoothScrolling(true);


    Button next =  new Button("",theme.getImage("next.png"));
    Button home =  new Button("",theme.getImage("home.png"));
    Button back =  new Button("",theme.getImage("back.png"));

    next.setUIID("ButtonNext");
    back.setUIID("ButtonBack");
    home.setUIID("ButtonHome");
    next.addActionListener((e)->{
        don.forward();
    });
    home.addActionListener((e)->{
        don.setURL("http://mywebsite.org");
    });
    back.addActionListener((e)->{
        don.back();
    });
    Container grid = new Container(new GridLayout(1,3));
    grid.add(back).add(home).add(next);

    hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,grid);
    hi.getToolbar().setHidden(true);

    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,don);
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS requires HTTPS URL's starting with iOS 9 for pretty much everything. If you have a good reason to disable this you might be able to get an app thru Apples review process see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html